# Android memory leak, on entering activity and press back, memory doesnot return to original value

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have a home class when i open task manager at home class it shows 15 MB of ram.

then on opening BooksDetails class it increases to 29 MB.

on Clicking back memory does not return 15MB

Here is  a sample

```
public class BooksDetails extends Activity
{
    private Button btnBack;
    private TextView tvBookTitle, tvBookSentences, tvBookInSummary, tvSpecialSentences;
    private JustifiedTextView tvBookTxt;
    private Button btnFavorite, btnShare, btnRelated;
    public book mBook;
    private Share ds;
    private Button btnShareFacebook, btnShareTwitter, btnShareGooglePlus,btnCancelShare;// bookShare

    private int idCount;
    private IDGENERATOR idGen;
    private String uniqueTag;

    // private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private ProgressWheel mProgress;
    // getBookText getBookTextTask;

    public int homeBookId;
    private static int count = 0;

    public static int ifDidntFindAnId = -1;

    public static boolean shouldTerminate = false;
    public static int terminateCount = 0;

    private int currentTerminateCount = 0;
    private boolean isAppRunning = true;

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

    private enum PendingAction
    {
            NONE, POST_PHOTO, POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception)
            {
                    onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
            }
    };

    private String user_id = null;
    private int isFavourite = -1;

    BooksDetailsHelp booksDetailsHelp;

    private FontMan fMan;

    public FontMan getFontMan()
    {
            if (fMan == null)
            {
                    fMan = FontMan.getInstance(this);
            }
            return fMan;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            // processing
    }
```

And

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (uiHelper != null)
                    uiHelper.onDestroy();
            destroy();
    }

    private void destroy()
    {
            try
            {
                    tvBookTxt.destroy();
                    Globals.destroy(findViewById(R.id.rootView));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

            btnBack = null;
            tvBookTitle = tvBookSentences = tvBookInSummary = tvSpecialSentences = null;
            tvBookTxt = null;
            btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(null);
            btnShare.setOnClickListener(null);
            btnRelated.setOnClickListener(null);
            btnFavorite = btnShare = btnRelated = null;
            mBook = null;
            ds = null;

            btnShareFacebook.setOnClickListener(null);
            btnShareTwitter.setOnClickListener(null);
            btnShareGooglePlus.setOnClickListener(null);
            btnCancelShare.setOnClickListener(null);

            btnShareFacebook = btnShareTwitter = btnShareGooglePlus = btnCancelShare = null;
            idGen = null;
            uniqueTag = null;
            mProgress = null;
            uiHelper = null;
            pendingAction = null;
            callback = null;
            user_id = null;
            booksDetailsHelp.destroy();
            booksDetailsHelp = null;

            fMan = null;
            if (getUserSocialIdsTask != null)
            {
                    getUserSocialIdsTask.cancel(true);
            }
            getUserSocialIdsTask = null;

            finish();
            System.gc();
    }

    public synchronized static void destroy(View homeView)
    {
            try
            {
                    disableListeners(homeView);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    // TODO: handle exception
            }
            try
            {
                    unbindDrawables(homeView);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
        }
    }

    private static void disableListeners(View view)
    {
            try
            {
                    view.setOnClickListener(null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    // TODO: handle exception
            }

            if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
            {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
                    {
                            disableListeners(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                    }
            }
    }

    private static void unbindDrawables(View view)
    {
            if (view.getBackground() != null)
            {
                    view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
            }
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
            {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
                    {
                            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                    }
                    ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            }
    }
```

here is an image after clicking the back button

[image: mat hprof]

Comment: Please realize that clicking the BACK button doesn't cause an immediate call to `onDestroy()`, nor does it necessarily cause a call to the garbage collector to clean up.

Comment: Almost everything in your second code block is unnecessary. Once the activity is finished, it should be unreferenced, so all of it's views will be unreferenced. Java is not like Objective-C...orphaned reference loops will be cleaned up by the GC. What could be happening is that you passed the Activity into something's constructor that was asking for a Context. Use `getBaseContext()` instead of passing the activity if this is what you did. Or like David said above, maybe the GC just hasn't got around to cleaning up this Activity yet when you are looking at it in the profiler.

Comment: Give this a lookin http://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: I can confirm by debugging that ondestroy was called and still 30mb of memory are allocated and after clicking cause gc button still the same

Comment: You may have to execute several rounds of GC before everything will go away. Circular references aren't always cleaned up in one go. However, it is possible that something is holding a reference to your activity, therefore preventing it from being reclaimed. Have you followed the chain of references back to see what is holding the reference to your activity?